# Why Mozilla Firefox Showing Security Warning for visiting http from https?

Tags: wordpress, firefox, ssl

Well, I am using Wordpress with CloudFlare SSL on my Website.
So basically My website is HTTPS and I found that there is a Security Warning Box opening when I click an external "Submit Form" with http from my Website.

There are still plenty of websites running in the world without SSL (HTTPS) so some part of my wordpress posts referring to http websites via "form submit" but whenever a user from Mozilla Firefox click over it, it will pop up a security warning to either continue or cancel.

Is there any solution to avoid this from my hosting area? I mean is there any script available to bypass this annoying box?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sy8S.png)

```js
<form id="ponyo_form" action="" rel="nofollow" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?=$_POST['filename'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="filesize" value="<?=$_POST['filesize'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_POST['id'];?>" /></form>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this warning?

Comment: Yes I can, but I'm not well aware how to share picture here.

Comment: Click "edit" and there'll be a button to attach an image.

Comment: That message comes with a form submission, not a link. Can you show us the code for the element that's causing the error?

Comment: Yeah, it's form, sorry to not mention.

Comment: I have added form code, well form id is form auto redirection to http website after few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot disable this warning for your users.

Firefox now [warns users when a page is doing things that risk their data being intercepted](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/20/communicating-the-dangers-of-non-secure-http/). Submitting a form on a HTTPS page to a HTTP endpoint is one such potentially insecure action.

Comment: Hmmm. Well at other hand, Chrome is working fine then.

Comment: Well, Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Adorable Chrome's getting stricter on HTTPS as well. I'd expect them to implement this warning at some point in the future, too. They've already got some warnings Firefox doesn't have yet.

Comment: I think you are actually right about it. I am now seeing that Google Chrome just turned all non-http links and src image to https, even though original contents are with http. This is some kind of conflict with http and https. You can't simply put anything with http on your https website.

Comment: Correct. A HTTPS page should have no HTTP assets (CSS, JS, images) or form actions. You can link off to HTTP URLs with `<a>` tags etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Shared web hosting service probably your hosing disable your SSL and you should contact your hosting service to fix that problem .Cloud Flare most of the time doesn't work on Shared web hosting .

Comment: Yes I am using Shared Web hosting but I don't think so that is there any issue with Cloudflare, it's something firefox relating problem, because there is no Security Warning with Chrome Browser.

Comment: If you think there is no issue with hosting try to reset your Firefox . enter about:support in URL and refresh your browser .

Comment: Tried it but unsuccessful